# Why is no unittest is running ?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have created some unittests and they are not running.Why is that so.

```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
        import unittest
        unittest.main()


class TestInversion(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2)

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)

    def test_3(self):
        self.assertEqual(3, 3)

    def test_4(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, 4)
```

Comment: you code seems unindented

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to move the:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

to underneath the class.

The `import unittest` needs to stay at the top, as Martijn Pieters points out.

This is because the python interpreter is executing the `unittest.main()` first and then parsing the class. (As that is the order you have written your code.)

Comment: The import needs to stay at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `if __name__` test to the bottom (leaving the `import unittest` part at the top):

```
import unittest

class TestInversion(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2)

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)

    def test_3(self):
        self.assertEqual(3, 3)

    def test_4(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and then it'll work:

```
$ python test.py 
F...
======================================================================
FAIL: test_1 (__main__.TestInversion)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in test_1
    self.assertEqual(1, 2)
AssertionError: 1 != 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

By the time `main()` is executed, you need to have defined your test case; if you call `main()` at the top, no tests are defined *yet*.